# ios xcassets with subfolders

Tags: ios, uiimage, xcasset

In xcode 5 I can create sub folders in in xcassets.  However I am not sure how to access the UIImage later.

```
-low
--- test.png
-medium
--- test.png
-high
--- test.png
```

I would think that I would be able to do something like this:

```
UIImage *image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"low/test"];
```

However that does not work at all.  My guess is that its because the icons are named the same and the folder is flattened at some point.  So cannot I not really use a folder structure to house icons that have the same name?  Could not find anything in the docs.